# Rewrite short url to long one with HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

I want to give a link to my users like:

> mydomain.com/654564

When a user opens the link, it must actually open url below:

> mydomain.com/index.php?id=654564

I searched on google. All of results was about how to shorten a url (That is not what I need).

How can I do it with htaccess?

P.S: I'm using localhost with xampp on windows.